# JMC connect to WildFly Windows Service

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, jmc

I am trying to connect with JMC to a WildFly running as service on a Windows8 Machine however when I open up JMC it does not show the running Wildfly only the jvm running the jmc. Is there any special setting to be applied when trying to connect this way?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a problem with privileges, if the Windows service is not started with the same user as the JMC executable. If you don't care about security, you can work around it by adding these command line parameters to the startup

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7091
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.autodiscovery=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jdp.name=WildFly-Service
```

and it will show up as "WildFly-Service" in JMC automatically.